# Extract points from regular data.frame with coordinates based on SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, spatial-database, database

I have a regular data.frame called datos.merged

> class(datosmerged)

```
[1] "data.frame"
```

The last two columns are the corresponding geographical coordinates

> datosmerged[1,c(23,24)]

```
   XCOORD   YCOORD
1 2473520   668648.7
```

I have a file called shape

> class(shape)

```
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

I would like to use this very simple shape to subset the previous data.frame. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily coerce your data.frame to an sp SpatialPointsDataFrame object.

```
coordinates(datosmerged) <- ~XCOORD+YCOORD
  class(datosmerged)
```

Assuming that "shape" is a polygon, you can then use the "over" function to identify overlap between the two feature classes. An alternative is "gIntersects" in the "rgeos" package but it a bit overkill for you problem.

Here is an example

```
require(sp)

# Create polygons
r1 = cbind(c(180114, 180553, 181127, 181477, 181294, 181007, 180409, 
  180162, 180114), c(332349, 332057, 332342, 333250, 333558, 333676, 
  332618, 332413, 332349))
r2 = cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553, 180314, 179955, 179142, 179437, 
  179524, 179979, 180042), c(332373, 332026, 331426, 330889, 330683, 
  331133, 331623, 332152, 332357, 332373))
srdf=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(r1)),"r1"),
                              Polygons(list(Polygon(r2)),"r2"))), data.frame(ID=c(1,2), 
                              row.names=c("r1","r2")))

# Coerce data.frame to SpatialPointsDataFrame
data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y

# Plot Example  
plot(meuse, pch=19)
  plot(srdf, add=T)

# Use over function to add polygon IDS to points. Non-overlapping points will have NA 
meuse@data <- data.frame(meuse@data, over(meuse, srdf[,"ID"]) )
  meuse@data
```